# spread operator inside for of loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I am following some tutorial where i see this code

```js
itsCallbackTime(){
  for(const cb of this.callback){
    console.log(...cb)
    this._handleCallback(...cb);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre>Here cb is some array.</pre>
```

I don't get this, the purpose of for of loop is to iterate through iterable one by one and spread operator is to get all the value. How it can be use together.  i tried doing it for some array

```js
const someArray = [10, 20, 30];

for (const value of someArray) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(...value);
}
```

I got error of

> TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

help!

Comment: please post what code you have tried to be more clear.

Comment: @BhaskarJoshi please have a look

Comment: Is `this.callback` an iterable of iterables?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including the value of `this.callback`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can hold any kind of value, including iterable ones.

You example is failing because `10`, `20`, and `30` are numbers, which are not iterable values.

```js
const someArray = [
  [10, 11],
  [20, 21],
  [30, 31]
];

for (const value of someArray) {
  console.log(value);
  console.log(...value);
}
```